# Median line for a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm realizing a scatter plot with the following data:

> x = [1000,10000,2000,....]
>   y = [10,20,12,90,....]

And the result is the follow[image]

Now I'm searching to realize a median interpolation for all y-points, like the "smooth" command in gnuplot. Do you know if is there something similar in matplotlib?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way of easily doing this with matplotlib only.

You can use [scipy's 1D interpolation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html), which provides some routines similar to gnuplot smooth. You can then plot the interpolated line using matplotlib.